# How to upload pic to Amazon s3 bucket and subfolder and display using php foreach

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using the code here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/

...to create a bucket and subdirectories for users who upload pics for personal use when logged in.

After uploading the pics successfully to the s3 server, they are displayed in the html file in a list as such:

```
 <ul id="sortable-list">

    <?php
    $i = 0;
    $contents = $s3->getBucket("bucket_name");

    foreach($contents as $file)
    {

    $fname = $file['name'];                 
    $furl = "http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/".$fname;  

        echo "<li class=\"default\"><img src=\"$furl\" width=\"100\"></li>";

        {
            $i = 0;
        }

    }
    ?>
 </ul>
```

For some reason, the subfolder is getting recognized as a file inside the bucket and fills the first element of the `$contents` as `http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/subfolder/`, but of course is empty without referencing a filename.

The php I'm using is a modified form of page.php on the tutsplus.com tutorial referenced above. The code that pertains to the creation of the bucket and sub-directories is here:

```
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

        $fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
        $fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];
        $folderName = "subfolder/$fileName";

        $s3->putBucket("unique_id", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

        if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "unique_id", $folderName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
            echo "<strong>We successfully uploaded your file.</strong>";
        }else{
            echo "<strong>Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.</strong>";
        }
    }
```

Need help figuring out how to prevent the subfolder from being recognized as a file and creating an element in in the display. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several solutions:

1. (Easiest) If it ends in a slash, it's a folder. i.e. check substr($fname,-1) == '/' and you have a folder
2. (Neater) You can use the [get_object_list](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=amazons3/get_object_list) call withe a PCRE to only get files that have something after the folder name. This works well if you know the folder name.
3. (A possible, untested) Check $file['size'] - if zero then it's either a folder or an empty file. As you don't want empty files anyway, this could be an option.

Answer (score 2):

after using `putbucket()` function use `$folder` name like this:

```
$s3->putBucket("file_bucket", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
            $foldername = "anirudh/$fileName";
```

and after that use these function

```
if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "file_bucket",
           $foldername, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ))
```

Comment: I am working with AWS S3 and my S3.php file is not having the function `listObjects`.I tried finding it from [GIT](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php) but its missing their too!Can you tell me if its removed or deprecated?If yes whats the alternate.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : download library from https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php

Step 2 : configure it in your project

Step 3 : follow below code

```
            $fileTempName= $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'];
     
            $bucket_name = "your_bucket_name";
      
            $upload_folder ="foldername" (which is created by you (folder) in aws  )

            $companyId = "subfolder name";



           $s3 = new S3("your access_key", "your secret_key"));
           $s3->putObject($fileTempName,$bucket_name,$upload_folder.'/'.$companyId);
```